# JPA/Hibernate: ManyToMany delete relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two classes, say Group and Person with a ManyToMany-Relation that is mapped in a JoinTable.

If I delete a Person that has a relation to a Group, I want to delete the entry from the join table (not delete the group itself!).

How do I have to define the cascade-Annotations? I didn't found a really helpful documentation but several unsolved board discussions...

```
public class Group {
    @ManyToMany(
        cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.? }, 
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.?})
    @JoinTable(name = "PERSON_GROUP", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID") })
    private List<Person> persons;    
}

public class Person {
    @ManyToMany(
        cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.? },
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
        mappedBy = "persons", 
        targetEntity = Group.class)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.?})
    private List<Group> group;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Cascade **will not** clean up the leftover references to the deleted `Person` that remain on the `Group` object in memory. You have to do that manually. It seems like cascade should do this, but sadly that's not the way it works.

Based on the info provided in your question, I don't think you need any cascade options set on your `Person` or `Group` entities. It doesn't sound like they share a parent/child relationship where the existence of one depends upon the other. That's the kind of relationship where I would expect to see some cascade options.

Comment: hmm ok, thanks. btw. is there anywhere a usable documentation of cascading and how to combine the jpa and hibernate annotations in a sensible way?

Comment: I use Hibernate as a provider but I only interact with it via the JPA interfaces. I'm not the right person to answer questions about Hibernate-specific annotations. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is:

```
cascade = CascadeType.ALL
```

To remove the DB relation, remove the association from each group.  Remove the person from the Group.persons collection and remove the Group from the Person.group collection, then persist your person object.

Comment: I want to remove the association automatically when deleting a person object. My intention is to not have to do this manually. If I have to, I don't need cascading. Or did I get the Cascading-feature wrong?

Comment: You have to.  Cascading doesn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it on a database specifically (depends on your database and it capabilities). By adding "on delete cascade" to the foreign key of the relationship table.